# If/or not returning true

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-2016

Ok, so this one is raising my blood pressure. I have a report that checks the logistic route of a order like this

```
ElseIf LCase(rota) = "blumenau" Then
   wkdas.Cells(86, 5) = wkdas.Cells(86, 5) + 1.2
   wkdas.Cells(86, 6) = wkdas.Cells(86, 6) + 1
ElseIf LCase(rota) = "itajai" Or LCase(rota) = "joinville" Then
   wkdas.Cells(87, 5) = wkdas.Cells(87, 5) + 1.2
   wkdas.Cells(87, 6) = wkdas.Cells(87, 6) + 1
```

Now, first case there, it only has one logistic route city, and it works fine, the second one, with two logistic routes (that were treated as one logistic route in the report due to proximity but we have to keep as two routes in system for fiscal reasons), just. don't. return. true.

I don't know why. I went and inspected the variable `rota` as the code ran. It was "Itajai", went into the `if` statement with the `LCase(rota)` (`Dim rota as String`, by the way, I didn't forget it). Returned as false.

I thought, maybe it's some funky stuff with the `Or` there, right? So I did this:

```
ElseIf LCase(rota) = "blumenau" Then
     wkdas.Cells(26, 5) = wkdas.Cells(26, 5) + 1.2
     wkdas.Cells(26, 6) = wkdas.Cells(26, 6) + 1
ElseIf LCase(rota) = "itajai" Then
     wkdas.Cells(27, 5) = wkdas.Cells(27, 5) + 1.2
     wkdas.Cells(27, 6) = wkdas.Cells(27, 6) + 1
ElseIf LCase(rota) = "joinville" Then
     wkdas.Cells(27, 5) = wkdas.Cells(27, 5) + 1.2
     wkdas.Cells(27, 6) = wkdas.Cells(27, 6) + 1
```

It didn't work. It works with "blumenau" and other cities, but aparently it has a bone to pick with "itajai" because it just won't recognize the city. Does anyone has a better theory than "vba hates this one city"?

Comment: Check for trailing spaces? How is `rota` assigned a value?

Comment: It checks the client code and assign rota from the result, like this: `If wkdad.Cells(linha, 1) = "Cliente:" Then
            cliente = wkdad.Cells(linha, 2)
            wkpar.Cells(1, 11) = cliente
            rota = wkpar.Cells(1, 12)`
wkpar.cells(1,12) has a PROCV that finds the route from wkpar.cells(1,11) client id from another excel file that has the client registration

Comment: Reading values from a cell - so check the contents of the cell. Likely the contents aren't what you think they are.

Comment: I did inspect the variable as the code ran, and it showed that `rota` was indeed "Itajai", but using a Trim did work, so you're were right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `Trim` with `Select Case` to make your code easier to read and ignore leading and trailing spaces.

```
Select Case Trim(LCase(rota))
    Case "blumenau"
        wkdas.Cells(26, 5) = wkdas.Cells(26, 5) + 1.2
        wkdas.Cells(26, 6) = wkdas.Cells(26, 6) + 1
    
    Case "itajai", "joinville"
        wkdas.Cells(27, 5) = wkdas.Cells(27, 5) + 1.2
        wkdas.Cells(27, 6) = wkdas.Cells(27, 6) + 1          

End Select
```

Comment: Trim did work. The code is too big to change to Select Case at this point but it does looks a lot better to write and read than normal if statements, thanks!